# Gson toJson escapes fields that are Option

Tags: json, scala, gson

I have a case class like this:

```
case class TotalTest(f1: Option[String], f2: Option[String], f3: String)
```

Using `Gson`, I am trying to write the contents into a Json file, here's what I get:

```
val test1 = (new Gson).toJson(TotalTest(Some("a"), Some("b"), "c"))
val pw1 = new PrintWriter(new File("test1.json" ))
pw1.write(test1)
pw1.close
```

The contents would be:

```
{"f1":{},"f2":{},"f3":"c"}
```

Why would I lose the first two fields? Basically I have a highly nested object of a case class with a lots of `Option`s and am wondering an easy way to extract the results.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833279/scala-gson-cannot-serialize-optionblob)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358455/encoding-scala-none-to-json-value-using-circe) we can use `Circe`:

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.syntax._

val totalTest = TotalTest(Some("a"), Some("b"), "c")
val pw1 = new PrintWriter(new File("test1.json" ))
pw1.write(totalTest.asJson.noSpaces)
pw1.close
```